# Equalizer-product formula for $(\infty, 1)$-limits

Tags: ct.category-theory, infinity-categories

If $F : K \to C$ is a functor of ordinary categories and $C$ has products and equalizers, then there is an isomorphism
\begin{equation*}
\lim F \cong \mathrm{eq} \left( \prod_{k_0 \in K_0} F(k_0) \rightrightarrows \prod_{(k_0 \to k_1) \in K_1} F(k_1) \right)
\end{equation*}
where $K_0$ and $K_1$ are, respectively, the set of objects and the set of morphisms of $K$, and the two arrows are induced by a projection and then composition with a morphism $k_0 \to k_1$ or with the identity $k_1 \to k_1$.

I'm interested in a similar formula for limits of functors $F : \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{C}$ of $\infty$-categories (where $\mathcal{C}$ has all small limits) and it seems like a (possibly naive) candidate is the following. Let $\mathbf{\Delta}$ be the simplicial indexing category. There is a functor
\begin{equation*}
L : \mathbf{\Delta} \to {\mathrm{Set}_{/\mathcal{C}}}, \quad [n] \mapsto (\mathrm{Fun}(\Delta^n, \mathcal{K})_0 \to \mathcal{K}^{n+1} \to \mathcal{K} \to \mathcal{C});
\end{equation*}
here the second to last arrow is the projection onto the last factor and the last arrow is $F$. Composing $L$ with the limit functor yields a cosimiplicial object $X : \mathbf{\Delta} \to \mathcal{C}$. As a diagram, $X$ looks like the diagram above but continued to the right to account for the higher simplices of $\mathcal{K}$, together with degeneracy maps going from the product indexed by $n$-simplices to that indexed by $(n-1)$-simplices.

Is the limit of $X$ equivalent to the limit of $F$? When both $\mathcal{K}$ and $\mathcal{C}$ are the nerves of ordinary categories the answer should be "yes" because we can restrict the diagram $X$ at the subcategory spanned by $[0]$ and $[1]$ without changing its limit, but I am unsure about the general case.

Comment: I haven't read it yet, but there was a paper on the ArXiv (I think) about this exact question just today. https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.01798

Comment: This is precisely the Bousfield–Kan formula. You could look for Jay Shah's thesis.

Comment: Excellent, thanks both of you! I tried to look up the Bousfield-Kan formula before but what came up seemed unrelated. The paper linked by Simon Henry has what I need.

Comment: Hello! Rune Haugseng [has a paper precisely on the analogue of this question for co/ends](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.03758). Since co/ends of functors that are "blind" in one variable (i.e. split like $\mathcal{C}^\mathsf{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{D}$ or $\mathcal{C}^\mathsf{op}\times\mathcal{C}\to\mathcal{C}^\mathsf{op}\to\mathcal{D}$ through a projection map) are just co/limits, I expect you should be able to get such a formula for co/limits as a corollary! :)

Comment: Indeed, it appears there as well as (the dual of) corollary 2.18. Thanks! I have a lot to learn about digging for references...

Comment: @LorenzoRiva Oh nice! I often feel super confused about references for $\infty$-categorical stuff by the way; it's quite hard to find certain results in my opinion =/